# Authenticating message when user enter password and email using java

Tags: message, modalpopup

How to show message called authenticating when user enter his email and password and when the user login is complete it disappear ...
I mean i seen in almost every application that if the user enter his email and password a popup message is display which says that authenticating and when he is completely loged in the message disappear i want the exactly that window in java ...

Answer (score 0):

I Find out the solution of this problem just create a new undercoated jFrame with message "Please wait authenticating... "  and and show this jFrame when user press the login button and at that time set this jFrame disable with the following function setEnable(false).
So the user was not able to Close this Message...